# Is there a better alternative than abusing the IDisposable pattern?

Tags: .net, language-design

Consider the following (Microsoft-sanctioned) code:

```
<% using (Html.Form<HomeController>(action=>action.Index())) { %>

    <input type="text" id="search" />

    <input type="button" value="Submit" />

<% } %>
```

The `using` statement has but one purpose here: *to add a `</form>` tag to the end of the generated HTML.*

This feels dirty to me, for what I hope are obvious reasons:

1. It's not `using`'s raison d'etre.
2. It deliberately causes side-effects.
3. It's not intuitive that `Html.Form` would implement `IDisposable`.
4. The `using` statement is not actually required, but `Html.Form` will break without it (unless you emit `</form>` yourself, which kinda misses the whole point).

This is [not the only abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101524) that people have heaped onto the `using` pattern.

The question is, is there a viable alternative that provides the same stylistic/readability benefits as `using`, without making you feel like taking a shower afterwards?

Comment: I suspect that the Html.Form needs something more general nature. Not in this particular cases, but in general, a long running Html.Form would indicate that the subclasses can also have the same characteristic. With long running time, you saves lot of resources that you would use re-loading data and info into the Html.Form. Don't underestimate this cost, you will be surprised that some forms look like they can load easily, but they do not.

Comment: To be honest when I first saw this specific use I was like "omg, that is a brilliant way to stretch the using concept."

Comment: @WyattBarnett: It has its charms.  It's main disadvantage is that, if you're the next person reading the code, you need to know ahead of time that the pattern can be abused in this way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- it really depends on how you look at IDisposable. If you view it as some sort of abstraction around a proverbial unit of work then this makes loads of sense. If you are into the underlying resource disposal semantics then I certainly see your point.

Comment: Asking for a "better" alternative seems a bit subjective.

Comment: @ChadJohnson: I thought I adequately explained what I meant by "better" in the body of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in .NET currently.

`using` (by design) is the only thing that's guaranteed to have that sort of deterministic two-part execution that you can actually work with. (`lock` does too, but it doesn't expose anything you can hook into - and would be dirtier)

AoP solutions can maybe help, but I've not seen any that work well at the sub-function level, let alone in html templates.

There's the option of passing an anonymous delegate into a function (which then executes the lambda and disposes of the resource), but that's ugly:

```
Using.Transaction(new Resource(), ()=>{
  Foo();
  Bar();
});
```

And it has some limitations:

- The compiler won't enforce that the resource is a previously undeclared resource like `using` blocks do.
- You can't exit the lambda unconventionally like you can a using block (via `return`, `break`, `continue`, `yield`, `goto`)

  - *(though the yield case is a known language bug and the other non-return cases are highly distasteful)*
- You can't access `ref`/`out` params from the lambda.
- You can't use `unsafe` code in the lambda.
- You can't "[chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396092/1301752)" the using blocks nicely.

Most of these can be circumvented by using named methods rather than anonymous, but that leads to its own problems.

Comment: Hmm... The situation would be better if `IDisposable` were named something more general-nature, like `ITransaction`.

Comment: What I was kinda after was some code that could be written that achieves the same purpose... I envision a higher-order wrapper function that takes a function as its parameter, but I'm not sure  that would be as clean as `using IDisposable`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - and how would you tell the code where to close the form? Delegates are used in some cases for that sort of thing in some cases, but the problem here is scoping the open/close. There may be some trickery that the new async/await stuff can do, but I've not seen it - and I expect it would not be as readable.

Comment: @Telastyn A function that does something like `try { action(resource); } finally { resource.Dispose(); }` where `resource` and `action` are arguments would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: @doval - sure, that's (almost) all `using` does anyways, but I don't think that comes close to the readability requirement. And actions have their own limitations on what you can do in them.

Comment: @Telastyn I'm not too well-versed in C# so I'm curious: what are `Action`'s limitations other than not returning a value (which is something you can't do from a `using` statement either)?

Comment: @Doval - added via edit.

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler's guarantees are all that valuable. I can't imagine how someone could take steps to ensure a resource is disposed yet be unaware that it was allocated outside of the statement he added for ensuring disposal. It's not like the compiler can guarantee that a `using` block is used every time the resource is allocated either. Still, points for being thorough, and the other restrictions are actually interesting.

Comment: @doval - I would argue that it would be easier to misuse in the method, whereas the `using` block at least forces you to declare the variable there (preventing you from using the variable at least outside of the block). But yes - they're not super-valuable.

Comment: So I would argue that while your points about lambdas are true, a fluent-style interface goes a long ways. If the "elements" themselves are also built to act in this way, I believe you could construct a UI pretty well this way. I toyed around with this once because I was so fed up with XAML being complex but without the raw power of C# for bindings etc. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/jtrana/crimson/commits/9a5cf4d645d27a372bd3c79d155b0c3aa765c086?at=master#chg-Crimson/Controls/DummyModule.cs). At any rate, if it's lambdas all the way down, higher order functions can replace the using.

Comment: `using` also doesn't guarantee that the resource is previously undeclared: `var resource = new Resource(); using (resource) { … } resource.Boom();`