# destroy object once it won't be used anymore in flyweight pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to use flyweight pattern to return the same instance of my object each time.

```
public class ThingFactory {
  private static final HashMap<UUID, Thing> things = new HashMap<>();

  public static Thing getThing(UUID id) {
    Thing thing = things.get(id);

    if (thing == null) {
      thing = new Thing(id);
      things.put(id, thing);
    }

    return thing;
  }
}
```

This approach has the drawback that `things` will contain a reference to each `Thing` object, even if the object will not be needed any more. So the garbage collector cannot automatically identify and destroy those objects.

How can I destroy the stored reference though when I know there are no other references to it anymore?

Comment: Use a [`WeakHashMap`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-weakhashmap)

Comment: With flyweights, what's the point of destroying any of them before termination? The very point of flyweights is that you might need this exact object again if another `get()` comes in.

Comment: Your `ThingFactory` isn't what determines if you'll need more instances in the future.  Also what David said, `WeakHashMap` means `ThingFactory` would not be what prevents these instances from getting eliminated, assuming they were used no where else.

Comment: Leave the caching for the cache...

Comment: @Laiv, surely "flyweight" is just another name for a cache? I can't really see any difference.

Comment: The cache is an index. It indexes things from execution to execution for their later reuse. All of this without forcing you to adopt any specific design. Flyweights imply design since you have to divide elements by their most common and heavy parts so that they are calculated only once during the execution and shared by all the objects that need it (we usually have many of them). It doesn't mean that this common part should be "remembered" from execution to execution. The OP didn't implement Flyweight. It just implemented a very simple cache.

Comment: @Laiv, the OP's example looks [pretty similar to the flyweight code examples in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). So I don't think you are helping by trying to argue its not a flyweight implementation. And your description of a flyweight ("*...you have to divide elements by their most common and heavy parts so that they are calculated only once during the execution and shared by all the objects that need it...*") describes a cache.

Comment: This is Flyweight `HeavyThing heavyThing = new HeavyThing(); ... for(int i=0; i < 60000; i++) LightThing lightThing = new LightThing(heavyThing);` Then you can cache the HeavyThing or not for the next execution (threat, whatever)

Comment: @DavidArno but the values need to be weak-referenced I think, not the keys

Comment: If you destroy them before you finish the program how come this remains a flyweight pattern?

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with, you should also add metrics to track hit rate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple solution (untested):

```
public class ThingFactory {
  private static final HashMap<UUID, WeakReference<Thing>> things = new HashMap<>();

  public static Thing getThing(UUID id) {
    WeakReference<Thing> ref = things.get(id);
    Thing thing;

    if (ref == null || (thing = ref.get()) == null) {
      thing = new Thing(id);
      ref = new WeakReference<Thing>(thing);
      things.put(id, ref);
    }

    return thing;
  }
}
```

There are some tweaks to this that you might consider.  In my experience/recollection, the `WeakReferences` are cleared aggressively by GC so you might find that you aren't getting much value from the flyweight i.e. each object gets used once and then GC'd.  This will depend on usage patterns so YMMV.

A way to deal with that is to keep both a normal reference and a weak reference and then periodically check for `WeakReferences` that have been cleared.  Then you can use some logic to determine whether the main reference should be cleared.  For example you could have something like this:

```
private static class RefPair {
  final Thing thing;
  final WeakReference<Thing> ref;
  final long created = System.currentTimeMillis();

  RefPair(Thing thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
    this.ref = new WeakReference<>(thing);
  }

  boolean expired()
  {
    if (ref.get() != null) return false;

    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - created) > EXPIRATION;
  }
}
```

And remove the value from the map once `expired()` returns true.

Which would allow you to guaranteed that each flyweight will live for at least `EXPIRATION` millis.

You might also want to take some time to get a handle on using [ReferenceQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) because it can help with these kinds of things.  For example, in this case you could use the ref-queue to inform determine which references have been cleared.  You will need to understand how to use a ReferenceQueue if want to use [PhantomReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html).  A `PhantomReference` is actually more appropriate for this expiration solution.  If you are interested, I can show you how that looks.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the question of what exactly the flyweight pattern is and if this is it, you kinda answer your own question.

> How can I destroy the stored reference though when I know there are no
>   other references to it anymore?

Keep track of the references and remove it when there are none left

in c# you could use IDisposable to prompt the user to dispose of resources when they are finished and overwrite the methods to keep track of your objects.

in java I think you can do something similar with `AutoCloseable`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

When you get the object from the ThingFactory increment a counter and when close() is called on the object decrement the counter, and remove if its zero

Comment: `in c# you could use IDisposable to prompt the user to dispose of resources` -- Eh, that's how a lot of people read `IDisposable`, but that's not really a satisfactory definition of the interface.  Microsoft's official line is that `IDisposable` is used to clean up unmanaged resources, but that's not a satisfactory definition either; `IDisposable` is routinely abused to do things like [close  HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628384) and [other things](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344504).

Comment: yeah, using dispose to close html tags was a terrible use of IDisposable, but hey ho. The point is people know you are supposed to call dispose and use 'using' which automatically calls dispose. and in this case the cached/flyweight is the resource you want to free up (for whatever reason)

Comment: the WeakHashSet suggestion in the comment seems like a nice easy suggestion. Why is this answer better ?

Comment: I dont see how the weakhashmap will work tbh. maybe @davidarno can expand?

Comment: Aren't you just re-inventing reference counting/mark and sweep garbage collection, poorly?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds a bit like monads in Haskell. In theory, monads are monoids in the category of endofunctors (hope I got that right). In practice, monads are what lets you use `do` notation.